# Uploading profile picture

Tags: php, codeigniter

this giving me a hard time , please help me guys I'm still a beginner on this ..
[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMaqt.png)
[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6ekQ.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbYgS.png)

strong text
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE2OG.png)

Comment: Post the actual code in your question, not screenshots of it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest to take a look around and see how to ask a proper question, to increase the chances to gave some good answers from the community: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/tour. For example, could you please show your efforts and paste a snippet of your code?

Comment: @lloydie fyi, some may take back their downvote if you edit your question posting the code even though you already got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
```

to a string:

```
$data = $this->upload->data('file_name');
```

OR

```
$data = $this->upload->data('file_path');
```

depending on whether you want to store the file path or name in the database.

**Please note: in the future don't post screenshots. that is what the code block is for in the text editor.**